# Multiple if Result =

Tags: c#, sql

I'm not sure how to do this but I am trying to do this...

```
           using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand { CommandText = "SELECT ID FROM Products.Products WHERE PartNumber like '" + textBox8.Text + "'", Connection = sqlCon2 })
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd3 = new SqlCommand { CommandText = "SELECT ID FROM Products.Products WHERE PartNumber like '" + textBox9.Text + "'", Connection = sqlCon2 })
{
                sqlCon2.Open();
                object result1 = sqlCmd2.ExecuteScalar();
                if (result1 != null)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = sqlCmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                    textBox2.Text = sqlCmd3.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

but i want the result1 to have both sqlCmd2 and sqlCmd3.  How would i do this?

maybe something like?

This is wrong..... I just don't know how to write it correctly.

```
 object result1 = sqlCmd2.ExecuteScalar(), sqlCmd3.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: What would that even mean? What do you want the value to be? What would its type be?

Comment: if possible, I would do the math in another cmd and just return that, AND I wish the moderators here would quit down voting people for not being perfect <-- they should be advising you on what they think is wrong with your question

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how to put two results into object result 1

Comment: @JonSkeet, I think he want's to assign multiple values at the same time to the object.

Comment: if the scalars are integers, you can just retrieve them and add them up, no?

Comment: what are your queries?

Comment: added my queries @Kuzgun

Comment: Would an 'OR' in your query be enough?

Comment: Let's simplify it. If you'd write `object result = "foo", 5;`, what would you expect `result` to be?

Comment: @user3324892 : Simply store both value in string variable then concatenate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps what you're looking for is an `Array` or `List`. Both of these can contain a sequence of multiple values, which would allow you to do this, for example:

```
var resultArray = new[] { 
    sqlCmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString(), 
    sqlCmd3.ExecuteScalar().ToString() 
};

// Read results with resultArray[0], resultArray[1]
```

Another option is to assign each result to an object property:

```
var result = new { 
    OneResult = sqlCmd2.ExecuteScalar(), 
    OtherResult = sqlCmd3.ExecuteScalar() 
};

// Read results with result.OneResult or result.OtherResult
```

Comment: This is a good answer, because the resulting types are much more useful than the original `object` in the question.